# iOS: XMPP Reconnect with Old School SSL connection

Tags: ios, ssl, xmppframework, reconnect

[`XMPPFramework`](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/) provides an extension named `XMPPReconnect` for "accidental disconnections" and automatically reconnects the stream.

This works well on the setting of the normal connection:

```
[xmppStream connect:&error]
[xmppStream setHostPort:5222];
allowSelfSignedCertificates = NO;
allowSSLHostNameMismatch = NO;
```

but not for this Old School SSL connection:

```
[xmppStream oldSchoolSecureConnect:&error]
[xmppStream setHostPort:5223];
allowSelfSignedCertificates = YES;
allowSSLHostNameMismatch = YES;
```

The error `libxmlErrorDomain` as error code `4` with the description `Document is empty` was thrown continuously,

sometimes, the error `GCDAsyncSocketErrorDomain` as error code `4` with description `Read operation timed out` also thrown.

Please suggest me the way to make the `XMPPReconnect` work on the Old School SSL connection.

P.S. The XMPP server is `openfire` and the `PLAIN` mechanism for authentication.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the Reconnect Extension of the XMPPFramework knows about old school ssl connection. IMHO you will have to modify 'XMPPReconnect.m' function 'maybeAttemptReconnectWithReachabilityFlags:' to do something like:

```
if(self.usesLegacyConnect) 
   [xmppStream oldSchoolSecureConnect:nil];
} else {
   [xmppStream connect:nil];
}
```